# Вёрстка svg таблицы

Tags: javascript, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сверстать такое поле в **svg** таким образом, чтобы при наведении курсора на каждую ячейку - она *подсвечивалась*, но в то же время не прописывать каждую клеточку вручную и отдельно? Прописать нужно только контуры, все эти цвета не нужны

Кода нет, т к нет идей

Comment: Красивая картинка. Верстайте без подсветки - это лишнее.

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, условия ставлю не я). Подсветка помогает пользователю понять на какое число он ставит

Comment: Вопросы некорректно задаёте. При наведении контур ячейки подсвечивайте. `не прописывать каждую клеточку вручную и отдельно` - вы предполагаете наличие волшебного скрипта, который это сделает? Начните верстать, с подсветкой после разберетесь. Три топора )

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, думал, ровные квадратные клеточки можно циклом создать

Comment: Найдите единообразный подход к решению данного вопроса независимо от формы ячейки: будь это квадратная ячейка или сегмент окружности.

Comment: таблица же статичная и это значит что можно нарисовать в любом редакторе